# Error with the tag Link, react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-router-dom, enzyme

I am doing a React challenge, it just asks me to put a Link tag from react router and it should have a text, it works perfectly in the browser but I can't pass the test, it keeps showing me an error, and I have tried literally everything.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Nav extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/"></Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/house/create"></Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <Link to="/house/create">Create House</Link>
                </li>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

export default Nav;
```

Here is the test code, the first one is passing, the other two are the ones that I can not pass.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { configure, shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";
import isReact from "is-react";


import Nav from "../src/components/Nav/Nav";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe("<Nav />", () => {
    let nav;
    // Si o si vas a tener que usar class component! No van a correr ninguno de los tests si no lo haces. <3
    beforeEach(() => {
        nav = shallow(<Nav />);
        expect(isReact.classComponent(Nav)).toBeTruthy();
    });

    it('Debería renderizar dos <Link to="" />. El primero que vaya a "/", y el segundo a "/house/create"', () => {
        // Podes importar el componente Link de react-router-dom.
        expect(nav.find(Link).length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(2);
        expect(nav.find(Link).length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(2);
        expect(nav.find(Link).at(0).prop('to')).toEqual('/');
        expect(nav.find(Link).at(1).prop('to')).toEqual('/house/create');
    });

    it('Debería tener un Link con el texto "Home" que cambie la ruta hacia "/"', () => {
        // El orden en el que se declaran los Links es importante!
        expect(nav.find(Link).at(0).prop("to")).toEqual("/");
        expect(nav.find(Link).at(0).text()).toEqual("Home");
    });

    it('Debería tener un segundo Link, con texto "Create House" y que cambie la ruta hacia "/house/create"', () => {
        expect(nav.find(Link).at(1).prop("to")).toEqual("/house/create");
        expect(nav.find(Link).at(1).text()).toEqual("Create House");
    });
});
```

when I run the test, it says it is receiving an empty string instead of "Home" or "Create House". I can not find a solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to run your tests I think the issue is that you added 2 more `Link` components and edited those instead of the initial two `Link` components.

You can read from the unit tests that it's expecting to see *at least* 2 link components, but then only explicitly checks the first two. `nav.find(Link)` returns an array of the found/matched element/component and only elements/components *at* indices 0 and 1 are tested.

```
describe("<Nav />", () => {
  let nav;
  beforeEach(() => {
    nav = shallow(<Nav />);
    expect(isReact.classComponent(Nav)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('Debería renderizar dos <Link to="" />. El primero que vaya a "/", y el segundo a "/house/create"', () => {
    expect(nav.find(Link).length).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(2);

    // Test the first found link
    expect(nav.find(Link).at(0).prop('to')).toEqual('/');

    // Test the second found link
    expect(nav.find(Link).at(1).prop('to')).toEqual('/house/create');
  });

  // Tests the first found link
  it('Debería tener un Link con el texto "Home" que cambie la ruta hacia "/"', () => {
    expect(nav.find(Link).at(0).prop("to")).toEqual("/");
    expect(nav.find(Link).at(0).text()).toEqual("Home");
  });

  // Tests the second found link
  it('Debería tener un segundo Link, con texto "Create House" y que cambie la ruta hacia "/house/create"', () => {
    expect(nav.find(Link).at(1).prop("to")).toEqual("/house/create");
    expect(nav.find(Link).at(1).text()).toEqual("Create House");
  });
});
```

The `Nav` component is rendering four `Link` components.

```
class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li>
          <Link to="/"></Link> // index 0
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/house/create"></Link> // index 1
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link> // index 2
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/house/create">Create House</Link> // index 3
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

The first test passes because it's only testing the `to` prop, but the next two tests fail because they are missing the link text.

I think the solution is to remove the first two links so the second two with text values are what get tested.

```
class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link> // index 0
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/house/create">Create House</Link> // index 1
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  };
};
```

Because the second two tests both test the `to` prop, the first test testing only the `to` prop is completely redundant and could/should be removed.